# How can I have text wrap around an image in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, text-wrap

I'm designing a flyer in Illustrator that explains the flavor profile of a product. I want the text to be to the right of a circular image and curve with the bottle cap. How can I alter the left side of the text box to wrap around the image?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the pen tool to add, remove and adjust anchor points on a text frame exactly as you can with any other path. For example:

[image]

A much better option though is to create a text wrap with the object you want to wrap the text around. Simply select the object and go to ***"Object → Text Wrap → Make"***.

You can adjust the offset by selecting ***"Text Wrap Options"*** from the same menu.

[image]